When receiving the host using next/headers in Next.js and making a request to the BE, a response for B.com is returned for a request made to A.com
I am using Next.js 13 and the infrastructure is running on ECS Docker.
We have various customer metadata configured in the back office. We are fetching this data during the process of using generateMetadata.
In this scenario, the BE server uses:
import { headers } from 'next/headers';
headers().get('host')


to receive the hostname and identify the URL.
However, metadata from B.com is being delivered to the site A.com.
How should I approach this problem?
Next.js 13 - next/headers returning strange value for host
Is this issue related to the one discussed in this StackOverflow question?
Or are there other measures that can be taken to resolve it?
I have not been able to pinpoint the exact cause of the problem.
